# Code/Package for multiple planet simulation

Tags: planet, exoplanet, n-body-simulations

I want to do a quick study and some tests on the planet-star dynamics ( including the movement of the star). I'm looking for a code that simulates some planets orbiting a star. I've tried searching online and the ones that I found are either incomplete or do not seem to give realistic results. With that in mind I'm wondering if there is any code/package that does this already (in Python).

Comment: What codes have you tried, and how did they fall short? [REBOUND](https://rebound.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) looks interesting but it's hard to guess whether it would meet your needs.

Comment: Would a planetarium simulation help?  I assume the planet orbits are input but cant swear to that.

Comment: I just edited my answer and mentioned a few more options

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/where-can-i-find-visualize-planets-stars-moons-etc-positions may or may not be helpful

Comment: Thank you for the answers, REBOUND seems perfect for what I wanted and have been working with it for the past few days and getting results, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are of course serious Python packages to simulate solar systems out there, one of which might be found in [The random walk of cars and their collision probabilities with planets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04718) but I think that other answers that will be posted will give a more complete answer.

I looked into a "roll your own" script as described in answers to [How to calculate the planets and moons beyond Newtons's gravitational force?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23408/12102) If you don't need to propagate for millions of years, it should be pretty easy and extremely instructive to just do the numerical simulation yourself.

**update:** The Python package [Poliastro](https://pypi.org/project/poliastro/) may also do exactly what you need ([poliastro in Space SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=poliastro)), and while [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) does not do this, there are rumblings in Github issues about adding an orbit propagator to it in the future. [PyEphem](https://pypi.org/project/ephem/) has been depreciated (same developer as Skyfield) but I believe it also does orbit propagation of user-specified objects, though I'm not sure if it's n-body or just Keplerian orbits.

I think that [Universe Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_Sandbox) will work for you. See also [Is a General Relativity approximation available in Universe Sandbox (1 or 2)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26803/7982)

Though it is a complete program and not in Python, Scott Manley talks about Universe Sandbox in [several videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/szyzyg/search?query=sandbox).

- old one from 2014 is [Universe Sandbox 2 (Alpha) - Simulate The Universe For Fun!](https://youtu.be/2JDYSmzYuyE)
- ["The Goblin" and an Exomoon The Size Of Neptune - Universe Sandbox](https://youtu.be/McsIvz1mwa4)
- [Universe Sandbox² - Planet Nine, Asteroids Orbiting Earth & more](https://youtu.be/TM11Jahqeys)

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer! Poliastro seems to be the one that best fits my interests from those mentioned, I will let you know if everything works!

Comment: @T.Silva that's great news; it will be great to hear how it goes, thanks!